# Чем Gulp лучше Prepros?

Tags: вёрстка, gulp, gulp-sass

ДЕнь добрый!
Вижу большую востребованность Gulp-а среди работодателей.
Думал изучить Gulp, но не вижу смысла в этом - "шило на мыло менять".

На сайте Gulp и в интернете искал, не могу найти ответ и поэтому продолжаю использовать Prepros.

Prepros мне дает:

- компиляции кода;
- минификации кода;
- оптимизация img;
- синхронизация верстки с браузером;
- css-префиксы

Подскажите.
Чем Gulp превосходит Prepros по функциональности и прочим возможности?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31419963/whats-the-benefit-using-gulp-over-prepros

Answer (score 2):

Самому стало интересно, активно покопался. Интересно, что прямого сравнения не найти даже в англоязычном сегменте. И, вероятно, связано это с тем, что сравнивать их нет большого смысла. Они несколько для разного предназначены.
Gulp - в первую очередь автоматизация в больших проектах, он для командной работы больших команд. Он мощнее и сложнее Prepros, он сделает всё, что делает Prepros, но будет сложнее в настройке. Если вы работаете в одиночку или проекты небольшие - вряд ли он вам нужен.
Вот пример некоторых типовых задач Gulp - решите сами, возможно ли это легко применить на Prepros, особенно для большой команды: https://webkyrs.info/page/chto-takoe-gulp-i-zachem-eto-nuzhno

Comment: Да, статья по Вашей ссылке интересна, чтоб получить краткий обзор Gulp-а.
Но:
 - Задача 1. Минификация кода.
 - Задача 3. Работа с CSS препроцессорами: sass, less, …
 - Задача 4. Поддержка новых стандартов языка Javascript. 
И даже больше дает Prepros не заморачиваясь.

"Задача 2. Объединение кода из разных файлов в один.  ... объединять код из CSS, Javascript файлов и.т.д. в один .. " не проверял. Но @import формата в одноименный формат объединяет код.

Пока преимуществ над Prepros не видно.